# How can I check that one text contains part of another (random) text in cypress

Tags: javascript, random, text, cypress, contains

How can I check that one text contains part of another (random) text in cypress
Example below

```
const _numberofcity = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 -1) + 1))
let nameofcity1, a_sentence;
    cy.xpath("div").eq(_numberofcity).invoke('text').then((text1) => {
    nameofcity1 = text1;
    });
    cy.xpath ("div").eq(_numberofcity).click()//London, Tokyo, Berlin...
    cy.xpath("p")//(Eq city) in top 20 cities in the world for 2023!
    .invoke('text').then((text2) => {
    a_sentence = text2;
    expect(a_sentence).to.contain('text', nameofcity1);
```

> expected 'Berlin in top 20 cities in the world for 2023! '\n
> Berlin\n

Comment: You should change `expect(a_sentence).to.contain('text', nameofcity1);` to `expect(a_sentence).to.contain(nameofcity1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can test at the string (text) level or the element level with `.should()`.

Here are two working examples:

```js
cy.get('div').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 -1) + 1))
  .invoke('text').then(randomCity => {

    cy.get('div').eq(numberofcity).click() // first we take Manhatten...

    cy.get('p')  // Manhatten in top 20 cities in the world for 2023!
      .invoke('text')
      .should('include', randomCity)
  })
```

or else this

```js
cy.get('div').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 -1) + 1))
  .invoke('text').then(randomCity => {

    cy.get('div').eq(numberofcity).click() // first we take Manhatten...

    cy.get('p')  // Manhatten in top 20 cities in the world for 2023!
      .should('contain', randomCity)
  })
```